# What do you think, is teaching on an actual board more efficient than using an online board?

Tags: undergraduate-education, technology-in-education, online-instruction, online, lecturing

I am a sophomore math undergraduate and so far all of my university courses have been online due to the pandemic. I am really curious what you guys think about the efficiency of teaching mathematics via a drawing tablet compared to teaching it using the regular blackboards/whiteboards/whatever other types of boards exist that are found in most lecture halls.

Let me give some motivation for this question since I think that it may seem odd for a student to ask this. Many of my professors claim that online math lecturing is not as good as in person math lecturing due to the limited space you have when you use a drawing tablet (Note: I am only going to focus on this point in this question. It is quite obvious that in person teaching is much better because we are social beings, but I want to discuss this particular aspect of online teaching). By this they mean that instead of having, say, 3 blackboards that you can write on, you just have as much space as your screen and that's basically it. Since I have only taken university math courses online, I can't really decide whether they are right about this and I don't want to judge based only on my high school experience. But the fact that this has been constantly brought up by many different people has inevitably got me thinking about whether my lectures would be much better (I have to mention that I believe that they are good in general) if classes were in person or if this is just something that stems from, say, a more canonical view towards lecturing. If you ask me, the biggest advantage of these drawing tablets is that the professor can save their notes and then send them to their students and in this way you basically get "free" lecture notes (by free I mean that the lecturer doesn't need to spend some extra time typesetting some notes, he just maybe has to polish a bit what he wrote). I find this to be superior to the traditional setting where you have to worry about getting the notes from someone in case you have some emergency and can't attent the lecture. In my view this advantage is pretty big and it seems to me that maybe after the pandemic is over and everyone resumes in person classes these drawing tablets could still be useful for some lectures if not all. But then again, my university education so far has been online, so I don't think that I am necessarily right. That's why I thought that this may be a good question to ask here.

Comment: I love writing on my ipad, using goodnotes. If the pandemic ever is truly over, I might still write on the ipad and have it display on the screen up front. I don't polish my notes (usually). And yes, students do love having them.

Comment: @SueVanHattum thanks for your input! I am glad that an actual lecturer feels the same way about this, i.e. that maybe using drawing tablets is going to be something valuable even after the pandemic is over. Just out of curiosity, do you feel that writing on your iPad is any slower than writing on an actual board or that this way of teaching has slowed down the pace of your lectures?

Comment: No. It's being online that slows things down. But it is a little bit of extra work to upload my notes. (And online teaching is about 50 different little bits of extra work adding up to tons more work. Teaching just 3 classes was too much.) Teachers who want to go back to the whiteboard may be just feeling the extra work load.

Comment: @SueVanHattum I see, so probably the "hate" towards the drawing tablets is in fact towards the online environment (which is reasonable since I guess most people hate it because it feels unnatural). Thank you very much for your comments, I am really glad that I could find the opinion of an actual impartial (in the sense that you are not someone from my uni) lecturer.